# How to pass null or empty to FetchXML filters?

Tags: filter, dynamics-crm-2011, fetchxml

Scenario: I've a text field in Dynamics CRM on Order Type. This field is integrated with some other systems and it'll be accepting only already stated list of values; like, ABC, IJK, XYZ etc. Now I can query this field using Advanced find if it contain data or not.

Now in report, I've a parameter that is having all those possible value and one additional as "Does not contain data" and its value is empty string. I've also enabled this report parameter for multi-select. But I am unable to get the orders if any of the value is selected from report parameters.

Below is my FetchXML query, Please let me know what I am missing in below.

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="invoicedetail">
   <attribute name="productid" />
    <attribute name="invoicedetailid" />
    <attribute name="tv_ordertype" />
    <order attribute="productid" descending="false" />
    <filter type="and">
        <condition attribute="tv_ordertype" operator="in" value="@Order_Types" />
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot combine the values ("ABC", "IJK", "XYZ") with an empty string option. Think about how SSRS will parse the empty string into FetchXml:

```
<condition attribute="tv_ordertype" operator="in" value="" />
```

Because the `in` operator has an empty string, there will be no matching results.

One approach that might work is to change your FetchXml to use an `or` filter, like this

```
<filter type="or">
    <condition attribute="tv_ordertype" operator="null" />
    <condition attribute="tv_ordertype" operator="in" value="@Order_Types" />
</filter>
```

This will now return all values from CRM that match your criteria OR have a null `tv_ordertype`

Then you can apply additional filtering at the tablix / report level

Comment: What is "@Order_Types"? I can't find any documentation on this type of variable that starts with @ in FetchXML.

Comment: @Shadowfax it's from the original question

Comment: right, it is in the original question, but is it a valid variable or is it just some gibberish meant as a placeholder?

Comment: @Shadowfax oh, I think you can either do comma-separated values, but normally it would be like this: `<condition attribute="tv_ordertype" operator="in" ><value>option1</value><value>option2</value></condition>`

Answer (score -1):

Try something like below

```
  <fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
    <entity name="invoicedetail">
        <attribute name="productid" />
        <attribute name="invoicedetailid" />
        <attribute name="tv_ordertype" />
        <order attribute="productid" descending="false" />      
        <filter type='and'>         
<condition attribute="tv_ordertype" operator="in" value="@Order_Types" />
        </filter>
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

Comment: it don't work out for me and ended up on error: `The FetchXML parameter "@Order_Types" cannot obtain multiple values. Change Parameter "@Order_Types" to single value parameter and try again`

Comment: I updated my answer,
Does your parameter get all the Order_Types? 
Can you post screenshot of your Parameter and your Query.
Ref Link https://nishantrana.me/2016/03/04/sample-fetch-xml-report-using-multivalued-parameter-in-operator-in-crm/

Answer (score -1):

Your fetch XML should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
   <entity name="invoicedetail">
      <attribute name="productid" />
      <attribute name="invoicedetailid" />
      <attribute name="tv_ordertype" />
      <order attribute="productid" descending="false" />
      <filter type="and">
         <condition attribute="tv_ordertype" operator="in"/>
            <value>@Order_Types[0]</value>
            <value>@Order_Types[1]</value>
            <!-- etc -->
         </condition>
      </filter>
   </entity>
</fetch>
```